How to remove read-only hook in bitbuckets?
I have jira connected with bitbucket, I did some changes in both jira and bitbucket and I get the following error when I try to push
 ! [remote rejected] test_pre_hook -> test_pre_hook (pre-receive hook decline

I've done some research on google and I understand that I mess up with smart commit.
I found the following hooks in my bitbucket repository

I know from this page https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/remove-read-only-webhooks-under-a-workspace-1180149651.html, I cannot remove them in a "classic" way (like custom hooks).
I cannot open "view requests", it opens a page with We could not load the webhook details. Try to refresh page or go back to the webhooks listing. Go back.
I would like to know:

How I introduce this issue (where I should look to remove/reverse these changes)
how to configure these hooks, in order to not remove them
how to remove with curl since curl -u user:password --verbose  --location --request GET 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0'and curl -u user:password --location --verbose --request GET 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/workspace/project' return me no output message and zero as exit code, while in verbose mode they show HTTP/2 401


The webhooks you've found are how Bitbucket notifies Jira, Pipelines, and Slack of different events. They are not the pre-receive hook causing your trouble, and you should not mess with them. The HTTP/2 401 indicates that you aren't providing valid credentials in your API calls.

Do you have any branch restrictions set up in this repo?

@JimRedmond, no, I don't have any branch restrictions.
